# Wie buchstäblich kann ein Seitensprung sein?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ein Seitensprung bedeutet gewöhnlich eine außereheliche Affäre.
Darf man dieses Wort auch buchstäblich benutzen?

> Nur ein Seitensprung rettete mich vor diesem Auto

Wenn nicht, was soll man dann sagen?

Answer (score 14):

*Der Seitensprung* ist tatsächlich der außereheliche (oder außerhalb einer festen Beziehung).
 Im gegebenen Beispiel wäre korrekt:

> Nur ein Sprung zur Seite rettete mich.

Comment: Es ist eine allgemeine Regel, dass getrennte Schreibweise eine buchstäbliche Bedeutung mit sich bringt, und zusammengeschriebene Wörter eine übertragene Bedeutung haben. Siehe: nahe legen / nahelegen, altes Papier / Altpapier, neuer Wagen / Neuwagen.

Answer (score 10):

Ein Seitensprung ist wie erwähnt eine außereheliche Affäre und kein Sprung zur Seite.

Die Aussage »nur ein Seitensprung rettete mich vor diesem Auto« macht zumindest neugierig auf eine interessante Geschichte. 
Wo passierte die erwähnte außereheliche Affäre, die einen vor einem Auto rettete? Fuhr z. B. ein Auto in den eigenen Garten und ohne die Affäre wäre man gerade bei der Gartenarbeit gewesen und wäre verletzt worden?

D. h., man könnte es als Wortspiel für eine Geschichte verwenden. Es verspricht etwas Außergewöhnliches und wird als lustiges Wortspiel aufgelöst.

Als sachlicher Bericht ist es aber falsch, korrekt wäre:

> Nur ein Sprung zur Seite rettete mich.

oder

> Ich rettete mich durch einen Sprung vor dem Auto.

Comment: "ìch rettete mich durch einen Sprung vor dem Auto" klingt aber auch lustig. Verständlich, aber keine all zu elegante Lösung :)

Comment: @Em1 Und was wäre eine elegante Lösung?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Ich sprang zur Seite und retette mich so vor dem Auto.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Der andere Vorschlag von knut. Oder der Vorschlag von Columbo; die Verwendung des Verbs finde ich hier besser, aber das ist natürlich persönlicher Geschmack.

Comment: @em1 Da hast du recht, es erinnert an _Ich rettete mich durch einen Sprung vor das Auto._ - was dem ganzen einen anderen Sinn gibt.

Comment: @knut Zum einen das, ich hatte aber auch das Bild vor dem Auge, wie jemand vor dem Auto stehend einfach hochspringt, eventuell in Actionheldenmanier sogar über das Auto hinweg.

Answer (score 6):

Laut [duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Seitensprung) kann ein Seitensprung tatsächlich der Sprung zur Seite bedeuten, ist aber dort als "veraltet" aufgeführt. Real kann man das aber heute nicht mehr in diesem Sinne verwenden.

Comment: Ach, sehr interessant! Danke, Veredomon.

Answer (score 4):

Ich widerspreche der wohl überwiegenden Meinung, dass „Seitensprung“ ausschließlich figurativ zu verstehen ist. Meiner Meinung nach ist es absolut in Ordnung, diesen Begriff auch buchstäblich zu verwenden. Ich denke, dass den Allermeisten in einer entsprechenden Textpassage **aus dem Kontext heraus klar sein wird, worum es sich handelt.** Ein einfaches Beispiel (schamlos von Wiktionary gestohlen):

> Das Pferd machte plötzlich einen Seitensprung.

Hier dürfte jedem klar sein, dass unser Hengst keine Affäre mit einer jungen Stute eingegangen ist. Jedoch wird auch ein Satz der sich auf eine Person bezieht, e.g.

> Er machte einen schnellen Seitensprung und das Auto verfehlte ihn nur knapp

keine andere Möglichkeit offen lassen. Das es sich um eine Affäre handelt ist schlichtweg ausgeschlossen.

Comment: … Echt jetzt? Ich ziehe mal die »das hat bestimmt regionale Ursachen«-Karte, und frage, aus welcher Ecke Deutschlands/Österreichs/der Schweiz du diese Beobachtung gemacht hast (die diametral entgegengesetzt zur meinigen ist)?

Comment: @Jan Hamburg, i.e. Norddeutschland. (Vielleicht liegt es aber eher an meinem Alter und dadurch an meinen tendenziell jüngeren Kontakten als am regionalen Vokabular.)

Comment: Ich stimme dir zu, dass im Kontext das natürlich jedem klar ist. Und ich glaube auch, dass in Bezug mit Tieren Seitensprung tatsächlich eher verwendet wird, weil dort die Doppeldeutigkeit wirklich nicht vorliegt. Aber ich glaube nicht, dass die Mehrheit die figurative Bedeutung nicht kennt....

Comment: @Em1 Natürlich kann die Mehrheit (welche sei vorerst dahingestellt) diesen Begriff kennen. Zu behaupten, dass sie derlei Ambiguitäten aber nicht ohne weiteres korrekt auflösen kann, wäre lächerlich.

Comment: Not my point. – Die Mehrheit der nativen Deutschen erfasst den Begriff Seitensprung ohne Kontex als Affäre. Erst im Kontext würde man es als "Sprung zur Seite" verstehen; hier aber in aller Regel als unnatürlich auffassen.

Comment: @Em1 Nein, das sehe ich anders.

Comment: Fair enough. Wie irgendwo hier schon von jmd anders erwähnt, sind immerhin im Duden beide Bedeutungen gelistet, wobei der "Sprung zur Seite" halt die Ältere Definition ist, die "Affäre" eher neuzeitig. Und verständlich ist es sowieso, immerhin gilt immer "Context is everything".

Comment: @Em1 Ich denke wir haben einfach völlig andere Umgebungen. Ich verkehre (wie bereits oben erwähnt) mit jüngeren Menschen die i.d.R. Dinge eher wörtlich nehmen. Daher würde es überhaupt nicht unnatürlich erscheinen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23081/discussion-between-em1-and-columbo).

Comment: Ich vermute mal, daß Du noch nicht mit vielen Menschen über einen Seitensprung gesprochen hast? :.-)

Answer (score 3):

Buchstäblich gemeint, könnten man "Seitwärtssprung" sagen. Aber mir gefällt hier "Sprung zur Seite" besser.

Answer (score -1):

Eine andere als die übliche Bedeutung von „Seitensprung“ könntest Du nur rechtfertigen, wenn jemand eine Seite springt oder eine Seite springt. Gitarristen können zumindest einen Saitensprung erleben.